# Cannot check if there is whitespace just before forward slash / in string JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check if there is whitespace just before forward slash / in string JS. I have this code now
`const reWhiteSpace = new RegExp("\s(?=[^/\s]*/)");  reWhiteSpace.test(values.body).` But it is not working as expected.

Comment: That should probably be `/\s[/]/.test(values.body)`.

Comment: you can try a manual approach, looping till you find a `/`, then checking its previous index

Comment: @SebastianSimon, I tried but always get false, here is my code : const reWhiteSpace = new RegExp("/\s[/]/"); reWhiteSpace.test(values.body)

Comment: Why wrap it in a `RegExp` constructor? Single backslashes are not going to work there: [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](/q/17863066/4642212).